# Took too long to shut down and was killed

Tags: django, django-channels

> ```
> WARNING Application instance <Task pending coro=<__call__() running at 
> /home/developer/projects/tabcon/tabcon_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/http.py:191>
> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[_chain_future.<locals>._call_check_cancel() at /usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py:431, Task._wakeup()]>> 
> for connection <WebRequest at 0x7ffa40e17b00 method=GET uri=/ clientproto=HTTP/1.1> took too long to shut down and was killed.
> ```

The above exception occurs and the entire service stops running.

I am using:

- channels==2.0
- channels_redis==2.2.1
- daphne==2.2.2
- Django==2.1
- channels_redis==2.2.1

Comment: did you find any solution? I am also fetching the same issue.

Comment: @KetanModi did you find any solution?

Comment: @AmmadKhalidM, can you please show your settings.py file configuration for channel_layer?

Comment: Check your Redis server, you may need to restart it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django channel Error "took too long to shut down and was killed."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62855104/django-channel-error-took-too-long-to-shut-down-and-was-killed)

Answer (score 1):

i got same problem when i try to disconnect the client from client side (by using Postman application ) , and i found the following solution , by raise a StopConsumer() Exception inside websoket disconnect method,  kindly have a look at the following official DOCs link https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/consumers.html#closing-consumers

and here is a simple example  :

```
from channels.consumer import SyncConsumer
from channels.exceptions import StopConsumer


class MySyncConsumer(SyncConsumer):

    def websocket_connect(self, event):
        print('websocket connected1...', event)

        self.send({
            'type': 'websocket.accept'
        })
        print('websocket connected2...', event)

    def websocket_receive(self, event):
        print('websocket recived message...', event)

    def websocket_disconnect(self, event):
        print('websocket disconnected...', event)  
        raise StopConsumer()
```

i don't know if my case same your case but i hope this helpful .

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is using `syncWebsocketConsumer` the syntax is the same as @K.A.'s answer, and resolved my issue as well. Thanks @K.A. for what should be the accepted answer.

Here is the async version of what fixed my issue.

```
    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        print(close_code)
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        raise StopConsumer()
```