# Django channel Error "took too long to shut down and was killed."

Tags: python-3.x, django, websocket, django-channels, django-redis

I am getting this error on my console log, and on form submit it keeps loading does not post data to the server.

> ```
> /home/Python/Working/Benutzerverwaltung/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/sessions.py:183>
> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at
> 0x7fab9fe51408>()]>> for connection <WebSocketProtocol
> client=['127.0.0.1', 59462] path=b'/ws/stream/Sales'> took too long to
> shut down and was killed.
> ```

Here is my code for closing the channel.

```py
async def disconnect(self, code):
    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
        self.room_group_name,
        self.channel
    )
    await self.close()

async def websocket_disconnect(self, event):
    print("Disconnect", event)
    await self.send({
        "type": "websocket.close"
    })
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 10):

This error is broadly because a coroutine is hanging around longer than it should.

**This specific case**

In this case, `AsyncWebsocketConsumer.websocket_disconnect()` is being overridden but is not calling `super()` which means that `StopConsumer()` isn't run (see [channels/generic/websocket.py:228](https://github.com/django/channels/blob/2.4.0/channels/generic/websocket.py#L228)). Perhaps don't override `websocket_disconnect` at all, since there's nothing in this example that justifies it.

Also note that `async_to_sync` is intended for sync consumers, but this is an async consumer. Instead use:

```
await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
    self.room_group_name,
    self.channel
)
```

The `await self.close()` isn't required as disconnect has already occurred. Remove that line.

**AsyncHttpConsumer**

Similarly in an `AsyncHttpConsumer` the mistake I've often made is to call `await self.send_response(...)` but then forget to call `return` afterwards, so the function will continue on when you didn't expect it to.

`AsyncHttpConsumer` also has an [open bug report](https://github.com/django/channels/issues/1350) about not surfacing exceptions within `handle()`. The only option currently is to adding extra print/logging lines to figure out what is/isn't running.

**Beware of django-debug-toolbar**

Also worth noting is that adding `debug-toolbar` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` will silence exceptions in your async consumers. See discussion [here](https://github.com/django/channels/issues/1340). Beware!

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says the following:

> Once you have finished doing your post-disconnect cleanup, you need to raise `channels.exceptions.StopConsumer` to halt the ASGI application cleanly and let the server clean it up. If you leave it running - by not raising this exception - the server will reach its application close timeout (which is 10 seconds by default in Daphne) and then kill your application and raise a warning.
> https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/consumers.html#closing-consumers

raising `StopConsumer` in the websocket_disconnect method fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this error.
Try to delete your env and create a new one.
The error will disappear.